# pyparsing read given number of characters

Tags: pyparsing

In the structured document that I'm parsing (with pyparsing), there are fields that consist of a piece of text (possibly including newlines) where the length of this text is specified beforehand. E.g.

```
len: 141
txt: Some text, possibly including newlines,
with length (counting each newline as 1 character) 141,
as specified in the preceding
len: 141 field.
len: 83
txt: There are multiple pieces of text, each preceded by their length (83 in this case).
```

I'm looking for help on how to do this.

Comment: Pyparsing includes a `countedArray` helper that might be useful as-is, or give you an idea on how you can write your own variation.  (In your sample text, are the "len:" and "txt:" labels present as well?)

Comment: @PaulMcG: Thanks for pointing out the `countedArray` helper, I think that's exactly what I need. The "len:" and "txt:" fields are present in my input text, yes.

Comment: @PaulMcG: I do have a follow-up question: if I want to just match (for a given N) the next N characters regardless of what they are: what to use to match any character (including whitespaces and newlines)?

Comment: `Regex('.{' + str(number_of_characters) + '}')` would probably work. Regex matching bypasses all of pyparsings whitespace-skipping logic.